# Grails: Tomcat War file deployment giving Memory exception

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a Grails 2.3.6 version application that am deploying in Tomcat 7.0.57

I have placed the WAR file in webapps folder in Tomcat. And when I do a server startup, I get exceptions in the console window. It looks like deployment is taking place OK, and the exceptions are being thrown after some time.

Please see below stacktrace: When i go to Windows task manager, jave.exe is taking almost 70 - 80% of CPU.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\
MY-1.0.2.war
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defi
ned
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.co
mmons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more in
fo.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Dec 22, 2014 3:58:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapp
s\docs
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\we
bapps\docs has finished in 30 ms
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapp
s\examples
Dec 22, 2014 3:58:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.SecurityConstraint.<init>(SecurityConstrai
nt.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRu
le.java:145)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1
288)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startEle
ment(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(X
MLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
ML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
ML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.
java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Ab
stractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.j
ava:1825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
a:1263)

Dec 22, 2014 3:58:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectories

SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen spa
ce
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
ava:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Ab
stractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.j
ava:1825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.jav
a:1263)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfi
g.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfi
g.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:87
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.jav
a:1245)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig
.java:1895)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        ... 4 more

Dec 22, 2014 3:58:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapp
s\host-manager
Dec 22, 2014 3:59:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectories

SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen spa
ce
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
ava:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Dec 22, 2014 3:59:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapp
s\manager
Dec 22, 2014 3:59:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapp
s\ROOT
Dec 22, 2014 3:59:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectories

SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen spa
ce
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
ava:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Exception in thread "quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" Dec 22, 2014 3:59:21
 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectories
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen spa
ce
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.j
ava:1148)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBa
se.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase
.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:34
7)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:1140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space


Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
n thread "quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread"
Exception in thread "main"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
n thread "main"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails uses more memory than you'd expect, and more permgen because of the dynamic code that is created at runtime. You shouldn't need to increase permgen all that much - try setting it at 256MB at first.

The best place to put JVM args for permgen and other similar settings is in setenv.sh (or .bat on Windows) in Tomcat's bin directory. It's not created by default and doesn't need to be executable, but it uses the same format as shell scripts. Any exported variables will be used in catalina.sh

This should be more than enough total heap and permgen:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Comment: In the "setenv.bat" file added - set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m and it worked!